Need help with part of a proof that $p(5n+4)\equiv 0$ mod $5$
Some definitions:
$p(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$.
Let $f(q)$ and $h(q)$ be polynomials in $q$, so $f(q)=\sum_0^\infty a_n q^n$ and $h(q)=\sum_0^\infty b_n q^n$. Then, we say that $f(q)\equiv h(q)$ mod $k$ if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n\equiv b_n$ mod $k$.
Problem:
Let $f(q)=\prod_{i=0}^\infty(1-q^{1+i})^5$ and $h(q)=\prod_{i=0}^\infty (1-q^{5+5i})$. By the binomial theorem, $f(q)\equiv h(q)$ mod $5$. Show that $\frac{f(q)}{h(q)}\equiv 1$ mod $5$.
This is from Theorem 2.3.1 to proof that $p(5n+4)$ is congruent to $0$ mod $5$ of Bruce C. Berndt book Number Theory in the spirit of ramanujan. Need help understanding this part of the proof im not sure how to author got to the step that $f(q)/h(q)\equiv 1$ mod $5$. Would be very helpful if anyone could provide some guidance.

Please don't use pictures to ask your question.  Pictures can't be searched, nor can they be interpreted by screen readers.  Nothing in that picture is hard to format, here is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Also, I don't see a definition of $p(n)$ in the picture.  Is it meant to be the standard partition function?  And I assume your header was meant to read $p(5n+4)\equiv 0 \pmod 5$?

yes, its meant to be the standard partition function, one sec will reformat the picture.

To the underlying question:  this is just the binomial theorem..  If $p$ is a prime, we have $(1+x)^p\equiv (1+x^p)\pmod p$.

@lulu i can understand how that gives us $f(q) \equiv h(q)$ mod $5$ but i don’t see why that would lead to $f(q)/h(q) \equiv 1$ mod $5$

When you compute the power series $\frac{1}{h(q)}$, you get some coefficients depending (via some polynomials, since the constant term is $1$) on those of $h$. Since $h(q)\equiv f(q)\pmod{5}$, you can replace all those coefficients with those of $h(q)$. Then you get the power series $\frac{1}{f(q)}$. In other words $\frac{1}{h(q)}\equiv\frac{1}{f(q)}\pmod{5}$. Therefore $\frac{f(q)}{h(q)}\equiv\frac{f(q)}{f(q)}=1$

@ameg ah okay i see it now thank you
